# Order php/mysql results based on google api calculated distance

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, google-api

It's my first question here, and english is not my main language, so... Sorry if i make any grammar mistake!

I have a very simple php script that does a echo of a `<ul>` of addresses from the Mysql database.

It's a database made with data from another software, so i don't have the Lat/Lon stored on it.

I can determine my distance from the address that i clicked with the Google API getting my current location, and using the `google.maps.Geocode` to convert the address into coordinates, then calculating the distance between us using `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon), new google.maps.LatLng(lat2,lon2)`, receiving a result in meters.

But how can i sort the `<ul>` based on distance? Is it possible with php + js?

I know this is probably something simple to do, but i'm just a beginer with web developing, and i couldn't figure this out yet. =/

Comment: Geocode your locations as you add them to database and do [Geo Distance searches](https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

Comment: What do you mean by sort here? do you mean to sort the UL asc and desc by distance?

Comment: @AbidNawaz Exactly

Comment: can you please post the calculated distances format ?

Comment: @AbidNawaz The Api give's a result in Meters like '658.7599605058606'

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good time to read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem. And at least post the code that you have. We can't possibly answer your question since we have no idea if or how it'll fit your situation.

Comment: @icecub Really? Really? Do i really need to put a script that just do a Select and displays the result as a list? All the API that i've used to calculate the coordinates and results are in the question, If i'm here asking something, its' because i'm trying to do this for days and could not figure out how. I'm not asking for a free coding or tutorial service, i'm just asking a question...

Comment: Relax m8. I'm not trying to be an ass here. There's nothing wrong with asking a question. There is something wrong with not showing us what you've already tried yourself. If you've been on it for days, like you say, I'm pretty sure you've tried several codes that didn't produce the result you were expecting. Show those to us! We can see where it went wrong and tell you how to fix it. Hover your mouse over the downvote button on your question. What does it say? Then tell me, where is the research efford in your question? I'm giving you those links so you can improve on your next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can sort the UL list of distances.

```js
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string")
    ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var vals = [];

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

  vals.sort();

  if (sortDescending)
    vals.reverse();

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}

var desc = false;
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
  sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
  desc = !desc;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="test" value="Sort List (click again to reverse)" />
<ul id="list">

  <li>658.7599605058606</li>
  <li>658.7599605058602</li>
  <li>658.7599605058607</li>
  <li>657.7599605058606</li>
  <li>659</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So simple and i couldn't figure this out by my self... I think im getting too old to do this =/ Thank You very much! It worked perfectly!